# I have made a recursive program to find set of all possible strings made of certain characters. Showing memory error

Tags: python, algorithm

I have made a recursive program to find set of all possible strings  made of certain characters. Here   set of characters are - A,C,G,T,-. I am not able to find the reason for the memory error and want to improve the logic.

```
a = ['A', 'C', 'G', 'T', '-']
def kmers(k):
    if k - 1 == 0:
        return a
    else:
        a1 = kmers(k - 1)
        a2 = kmers(1)
        i = 0
        j = 0
        a3 = []
        for i in range(len(a1)):
            for j in range(len(a2)):
                str = ""
                str = str + a1[i] + a2[j]
                a3.append(str)
    return a3

b = kmers(20)
print(b)
```

Comment: You probably hit the maximum recursion depth. Best to change recursion to iteration. Great tutorial here: https://blog.moertel.com/posts/2013-05-11-recursive-to-iterative.html

Comment: @Tim .But this works well : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-combinations-of-given-length/

Comment: Your string list gets 5 times longer on every recursion level and there are 20. And BTW for such operations there is the `itertools` module which is far more efficient than recursion.

Comment: Have you tried debugging yet? What were your findings?

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks I got it. Returning a very big size list --> that was the mistake I was committing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to find all length 20 strings made out of 5 letters.  There are `5^20 = 95367431640625` of them.  To represent 95 trillion things, each of which takes 20 bytes, would take petabytes of memory.  You probably are running this on a computer with gigabytes of memory.

That.  Won't.  Work.

I can tell you how to make something like this work, but it sounds like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What were you hoping to do with all of this data, and can you find a way to get by with something more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

The length 20 is too much. 5 possible characters with length of 20 gives, 5^20 different strings. Each string is 20 byte (20 characters), this requires 2000TB, or 2PB of memory.